# Firefox on Windows renders an image color incorrectly

Tags: image, cross-browser, webpage-rendering

I've run into this issue before without ever really figuring out what the problem was, but I'm attempting to do the standard "drop-shadow" effect by using an image border on the main content of my page.  The content portion has a blue background (#3366ff) so the border image has one pixel of that color before the "drop-shadow".  Everything works great in Chrome (Windows & Mac), Safari (Mac), IE8 and Firefox (Mac) but it falls apart on Firefox for Windows.  The images are below, but instead of rendering the #3366ff color, Firefox renders #4e50fb.  Thoughts?  Could this be a color profile issue? And if so, how would I go about fixing it?

Thanks!

Bad Rendering:

[image: bad image]

Good Rendering:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to an example where this is happening? It is hard to say otherwise.

Comment: @dstorey Unfortunately I don't.  The website isn't in production yet.  I can post code if you'd like it though.  Just let me know what you want.